# acess elements in arraylist of objects in javascript html

Tags: javascript, html, arraylist, var

I am new to html/javascript 
This is my class:

```
TravelObjects{
    String sourceName;
    String lattitude;
    String longitude;
    ...
    getters and setters
}
```

I am recieving array of `TravelObject` class as server response whose variables I want to use on html side. How do I iterate over this array of `TravelObjects` in javascript.

I tried using:

```
var x = '${result.arrayOfTravelObjects}';
```

I want to loop over `x` and retrieve individual values of `sourceName`, `lattitude`, `longitude`.

Comment: What does your javascript object look like?

Comment: Can you show the `TravelObjects` array that you receive from server?

Comment: "travelObjectArray": [
        {         
            "longitude": "83.3731675",
            "lattitude": "26.7605545",
            sourceName : "delhi"
        },
        {
            "longitude": "83.07",
            "lattitude": "26.78",
            sourceName:"khalihabad" 
        }}

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
result.arrayOfTravelObjects.forEach(function(travObj){
console.log(travObj.lattitude);
});
```